# Simple indexed mysql query is doing full table scan

Tags: mysql, indexing, unique, explain

Can anyone tell me why this query is doing a full table scan, even when using an index?
I've tried every combo of INDEX and UNIQUE fields and even when it uses an index it always seems to scan every row in table?

```
EXPLAIN 
SELECT *
FROM product_viewed
WHERE product_id_to = 414;
```

FIELDS  on product_viewed
 product_id_from (f)
 product_id_to (t)
 visits (v)

AVAILABLE indexes, etc.

> primary = f + t
>   unique_product_viewed_t_v_f = t + v + t
>   idx_product_viewed_t = t

Explain Results
    1, SIMPLE, product_viewed, index, unique_product_viewed_t_v_f,idx_product_viewed_t, unique_product_viewed_t_v_f, 209, , 67057, Using where; Using index

Example Table Data:,
f       t       v,
1002    1001    1,
1005    1001    3,
1006    1001    6,
1002    1005    1,

etc...

Comment: What makes you think it's doing a full table scan?

Comment: It says: `Using index` at the end of EXPLAIN, so you are wrong, that it's not using.